How to derive renko volume from candle OHLCV data
i have been recently trying to generate Renko bricks from my OHLCV data, I'm currently using stocktrends module and have successfully generated the bricks, but I'm having trouble with generating the volume data as shown in the trading graph. By far i have tried "summing all the total volume of candles corresponding to the formation of that brick", this works at a 60-70% correctness but the remaining volume fails to match with the trading chart, is there any method behind calculation of this volume, I've been trying to understand this by googling but haven't got any luck about "renko volume". although I've heard that volume is useless with renko bricks. This task is more off for a friend and i don't have a say in it, i just provided the tech support. It would be really helpful if anyone could help me with this, Thanks in advance.

on which market/exchange are you working? you may know that most equity markets are fragmented, depending on the provider you may have only the access to one exchange/venues whereas more (16 in the US) are needed. Usually open and close price come from call auctions of one specific exchange, but for the rest (even high and low), you need more data.

I'm from india and the exchange is NSE, I'm handling F&O data, the data vendor gives me data in OHLCV format for a particular instrument. In india, only NSE handles F&O trades, so there is only 1 data source.

I am not an expert in Indian markets, but p5 of https://www.newyorkfed.org/medialibrary/media/research/economists/sarkar/derivatives_in_india.pdf :
"The number of commodities eligible for futures trading has increased from 8 in 2000 to 80 in 2004, while the value of trading has increased almost four times in the same period (Nair, 2004). However, many contracts barely trade and, of those that are active, trading is fragmented over multiple market venues, including central and regional exchanges, brokerages, and unregulated forwards markets."
